# Calculate SUM in mysql query as alias field

Tags: mysql

I am trying to modify a query by adding a sum of two alias fields.

The original query is:

```
SELECT event_date.meta_value AS 'Event Date'
    , ugm.group_id AS 'Gig ID'
    , p_title.post_title AS 'Client'
    , event_venue.meta_value AS 'Venue'
    , wum_l.meta_value last_name
    , wum_f.meta_value first_name
    , wum_m.meta_value AS 'Miles' 
    , wum_mp.meta_value AS 'Mileage Pay'
    , wum.meta_value  AS 'Gig Pay' 
FROM wp_users wu
INNER JOIN wp_um_groups_members ugm
    ON  ugm.user_id1 = wu.id
LEFT JOIN  wp_usermeta wum
    ON wu.id = wum.user_id
    AND wum.meta_key = CONCAT('um_groups_', ugm.group_id, '_price')   
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta wum_f
    ON wu.id = wum_f.user_id
    AND wum_f.meta_key = 'first_name'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta wum_l
    ON wu.id = wum_l.user_id
    AND wum_l.meta_key = 'last_name'
LEFT JOIN wp_posts p_title
    ON p_title.id = ugm.group_id
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta wum_m
    ON wu.id = wum_m.user_id
    AND wum_m.meta_key = CONCAT('_um_groups_', ugm.group_id, '_mileage') 
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta wum_mp
    ON wu.id = wum_mp.user_id
    AND wum_mp.meta_key = CONCAT('um_groups_', ugm.group_id, '_mileage_price')
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta event_date
    ON event_date.post_id= ugm.group_id    
    AND event_date.meta_key = '_um_groups_event_start'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta event_venue
    ON event_venue.post_id= ugm.group_id    
    AND event_venue.meta_key = '_um_groups_event_venue'
 WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(event_date.meta_value, '%Y/%m/%d') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2021/1/01', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2021/1/15', '%Y-%m-%d') 
AND wum.meta_value IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY wu.display_name  ASC;
```

What I want to do is create a final alias field named `Total Pay` in which it calculates the sum of `Gig Pay` and `Mileage Pay` for each row.

The problem I was having is I was using `SUM` in my query and getting a sum of every matching row.  I just want the sum per row.

For example, an expected output would look like this:

```
Event Date  Gig ID  Client      Venue       last_name   first_name  Miles   Mileage Pay Gig Pay Total Pay
2021/01/15  49270   Joe Schmoe  This Event  Doe         Joe         2       120         732     852
```

How do I need to modify the query to show a new alias field with the sum per row?

Comment: What do you think `STR_TO_DATE('2021/1/15', '%Y-%m-%d')` does?

Comment: @Strawberry  Nothing.  I had a variable $start in there and I had just replaced it when I was testing the query directly.

Comment: OK. What do you think `STR_TO_DATE(variable, '%Y-%m-%d')` does?

Answer (score 0):

Simply addding the two fields should work based on the requirements.

```
SELECT event_date.meta_value AS 'Event Date'
    , ugm.group_id AS 'Gig ID'
    , p_title.post_title AS 'Client'
    , event_venue.meta_value AS 'Venue'
    , wum_l.meta_value last_name
    , wum_f.meta_value first_name
    , wum_m.meta_value AS 'Miles' 
    , wum_mp.meta_value AS 'Mileage Pay'
    , wum.meta_value  AS 'Gig Pay'
    , wum_mp.meta_value + wum.meta_value  AS 'Total Pay' 
FROM wp_users wu
INNER JOIN wp_um_groups_members ugm
    ON  ugm.user_id1 = wu.id
LEFT JOIN  wp_usermeta wum
    ON wu.id = wum.user_id
    AND wum.meta_key = CONCAT('um_groups_', ugm.group_id, '_price')   
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta wum_f
    ON wu.id = wum_f.user_id
    AND wum_f.meta_key = 'first_name'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta wum_l
    ON wu.id = wum_l.user_id
    AND wum_l.meta_key = 'last_name'
LEFT JOIN wp_posts p_title
    ON p_title.id = ugm.group_id
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta wum_m
    ON wu.id = wum_m.user_id
    AND wum_m.meta_key = CONCAT('_um_groups_', ugm.group_id, '_mileage') 
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta wum_mp
    ON wu.id = wum_mp.user_id
    AND wum_mp.meta_key = CONCAT('um_groups_', ugm.group_id, '_mileage_price')
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta event_date
    ON event_date.post_id= ugm.group_id    
    AND event_date.meta_key = '_um_groups_event_start'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta event_venue
    ON event_venue.post_id= ugm.group_id    
    AND event_venue.meta_key = '_um_groups_event_venue'
 WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(event_date.meta_value, '%Y/%m/%d') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2021/1/01', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2021/1/15', '%Y-%m-%d') 
AND wum.meta_value IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY wu.display_name  ASC;
```

Comment: This is an INNER JOIN